# XCode 6 beta 7 error with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Previous version is beta 6 , my project worked fine. I just updated my xcode to version 6 beta 7 and getting error , really don't know how to fix it.

```
var currentcell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
var posx = currentcell.frame.origin.x-collectionView.contentOffset.x
```

Error report: 'UICollectionViewCell?' does not have a member named 'frame'
Xcode 6 beta 7 suggest me add ? after current cell.
i changed it to

```
var posx = currentcell?.frame.origin.x-collectionView.contentOffset.x
```

But still error: Error report: Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. Using `?` in

`currentcell?.frame.origin.x` makes the whole expression an optional (`CGFloat?`). You cannot do arithmetic operations on optionals. You have to unwrap the value first.

What do you expect `posX` to be when `currentCell` is `nil`?

Probably what you want to do is to force unwrapping the cell value:

```
var posX = currentcell!.frame.origin.x - collectionView.contentOffset.x
```

In older betas most of the obj-c types were explicitely unwrapped optionals (`UITableViewCell!`) but some of them were made into pure optionals (`UITableViewCell?`). Note that there are cases when the `currentCell` is `nil`. You should handle these cases.

Comment: i don't have ? at the beginning, but xcode 6 beta 7 suggest for me to add ? after that.

Comment: @TomSawyer Probably you want to use an  `!`. In older betas most of the obj-c types were explicitely unwrapped optionals (`UITableViewCell!`) but some of them were made into pure optionals (`UITableViewCell?`). That probably made the difference.

Comment: Many tks, its worked now after added ! after currentcell

Answer (score 1):

To avoid runtime crashes when  no cell is returned for the given indexPath do:

```
if let currentcell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    var posX = currentcell.frame.origin.x - collectionView.contentOffset.x
    // .. do something
}
else {
    // ... there was no cell so do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if currentcell != nil
{
    var posx = currentcell!.frame.origin.x-collectionView.contentOffset.x
}
```